# How to add/change dot leaders with an apa6 document class

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, apa6

I've been having tremendous difficulty trying to add dot leaders for section titles (or maybe they're chapter titles?) on my thesis, because I'm using the apa6 document class.

I can't seem to get any of the commands with the Tocloft package to work because I feel pretty sure the apa6 class doesn't support most of the commands that are provided.  I keep getting errors when I try the renewal commands for section/chapter headings that were provided as solutions in other threads with similar questions (only they were for book or article classes I believe).

Does anybody have any idea how I could proceed?  I hope I won't have to change definitions inside of the document class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You write

> I can't seem to get any of the commands with the Tocloft package to work because I feel pretty sure the apa6 class doesn't support most of the commands that are provided.

I'm afraid I'm not able to generate a conflict between the `apa6` document class and the `tocloft` package. As the following example shows, the command `\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` succeeds in generating leader dots between the text of the section headers and the associated page numbers in the table of contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\title{Long and Elaborate Greetings}
\shorttitle{Short Greetings}
\author{XYZ}
\affiliation{Some great place}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Good morning}
\subsubsection{Hi}
\end{document}
```